# useFetch composable in Nux.js 3 is not working for localhost endpoint

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, usefetch

The backend is in python which has endpoint /blogs. When called from useFetch composable with http://localhost:8991/blog. I'm getting fetch failed error, but if I use  http://127.0.0.1/blogs it works fine.

Please explain me the logic behind this.

```
<template>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data, pending, error } = await useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8992/blogs')
</script>
```

Changed URL from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Depends how your etc.hosts is configured I guess. You cannot use `/blogs` directly?

Comment: The backend api is running at different port, so need to use the full url in useFetch().